# insert span in jscript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to do this:

```
text: pen
textarea:pencil penpen
div: <span>pen</span>cil <span>pen</span><span>pen</span>
```

and I have this:

```
text 1: <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br /><br />
<textarea cols="50" rows="20" id="txt2"></textarea><br />
<button id="btn">click</button><br />
<div id="rslt"></div>
<script>
if ($("#txt2").val().includes($("#txt1").val())) {
    $("#rslt").text($("#txt2").val());
</script>
```

I know I need to use indexOf() but can't solve this

Comment: Your code is running when the page is first loaded, before the user can type anything into the input fields. Don't you think you should run it in an event handler when the user changes the fields?

Comment: I forgat
$("#btn").click(function () {}

Comment: What's the problem? It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Lm609y3e/1/

Comment: @Barmar, it isn't that the OP is looking to have the textarea barfed straight into the result div, it seems the OP is looking to wrap matched members of the textarea. If you look at the div out put in "I need to do this:" it kind of hints at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using replace() is really going to do what you want, rather than splitting and rejoining the string. But the tricky bit is realizing you need to create a Regular Expression for this. You want to match multiple times, and you want a case insensitive match.

So I take the value of the first input, and I create a custom regex with that value. I search for the actual string in the first, and if its found, I go ahead and replace all instances in the output.

I updated teh CSS to show you that each instance of 'pen' (or 'Pen' or 'PEN') is wrapped in its own tag, hover over any of them.

Hope it helps!

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  // First, pull the strings out. Make life easier.
  let val1 = $("#txt1").val(),
  // I want it to be a case insensitive match, and to match multiple.
  //  So... REGEX!
    val1Regex = new RegExp(val1, "gi");
    val2 = $("#txt2").val();
  // indexOf() in action.
//  console.log(val2.indexOf(val1));

  // and if the search string:
  if (val2.includes(val1)) {
    // I want to highlight the found string, maybe?
    $("#rslt").html(val2.replace(val1Regex, "<b>$&</b>"))
  };
});
```

```css
b:hover {
  background-color: #C33;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
text 1: <input type="text" id="txt1" value="pen" /><br /><br />
<textarea cols="50" rows="20" id="txt2">Pencil pentacle penpen</textarea><br
/>
<button id="btn">click</button><br />
<div id="rslt"></div>
```

So it's HOMEWORK. Well, this won't give you everything, it doesn't case-match, but it gets you closer to what you want:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  // First, pull the strings out. Make life easier.
  let val1 = $("#txt1").val(),
      val2 = $("#txt2").val();
  // indexOf() in action.
//  console.log(val2.indexOf(val1));

  // and if the search string:
  if(val2.includes(val1)){
    // This is going to be the output HTML. I will have to
    //  build it, piece by piece.
    let myNewContent = "";
    
    // Loop through until the substring is no longer in the
    //   superstring.
    while (val2.includes(val1) ){
      // Our new string contains everything UP TO the found
      //  substring, plus our wrapped substring
      myNewContent += val2.slice(0, val2.indexOf(val1))+"<b>"+val1+"</b>";
      // the value of val2 changes. It should now contain
      //  everything AFTER the found instance of the
      //  substring, which may still contain MORE instances
      //  of that substring. Hence the loop.
      val2 = val2.slice(val2.indexOf(val1)+val1.length);
    }
    // Don't forget -- after the loop, we still need to add
    //  whatever remains in our 'superstring' back in!
    myNewContent += val2;
    
    // And display the edited string.
    $("#rslt").html(myNewContent);
  }

  
});
```

```css
b:hover {
  background-color: #C33;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

text 1: <input type="text" id="txt1" value="pen" /><br /><br />
<textarea cols="50" rows="20" id="txt2">Pencil pentacle penpen</textarea><br
/>
<button id="btn">click</button><br />
<div id="rslt"></div>
```

This is doing kind of the same thing, only old-school. What happens is, if there is ANY match of the strings, we have a while loop. That loop will continue as long as we have another match of the substring.

Within that while loop, I first append everything UP TO the indexOf position from the large string into a newly created string, adding the wrapped substring to the end of it. This new string will be our output value. I replace the large string with a version of itself that is cut shorter, as I remove everything from the FRONT of this one up to the index of the substring **PLUS** the length of the substring. That basically removes everything up to the end of the current substring, and the loop tries again.

I've tried to comment the code effectively. Best of luck.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use Regular Expression because it is the request in my assignment.
can I use indexOf for this?

Comment: @FeYa, I left the replace() answer, as it really is the best, but I've also updated the answer to use indexOf() and slice(). You'll have to loop, and you may still want to handle upper/lower case, I didn't bother.

Comment: Feya, were you able to get the logic of the second approach? The splitting and rejoining can be a little odd.